# String parsing i php

Tags: php, string, parsing

I need to create a php program that parses inputed text and creates different combinations of the sentence.  The input sentence should look like this:

```
$sentence = "{This is mine{example|task}}";
```

Inside `{}` is the separator `|` for two allowed values `example` and `task`.
The result should look like this:

```
This is mine example.
This is mine task.
```

I've tried this:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters, $string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return $launch;
}

$sentence = "{This is mine{example|task}}";
$top1 = multiexplode(array("{", "|"), $sentence);
$max = sizeof($top1);

for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
   foreach ($top1 as $a) {
       echo $a;
   }
   echo "<br />";
}
```

But I can't get it work properly. Here is the result I get:

```
This is mineexampletask}}<br />
This is mineexampletask}}<br />
This is mineexampletask}}<br />
This is mineexampletask}}<br />
```

Comment: You could use splitting or regular expressions. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? To see that you put some effort into it would be nice so we not just do your work!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Use the [**edit** link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27450692/edit) beneath your question.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new I don't know all the rules yet

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of regular expressions and splitting.

1. Use regular expressions to parse the bracket enclosed areas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression and in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
2. Split the inner bracket by your separator `|` http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

When constructing the sentence, make sure you're escaping the "example" and "task" parts so they don't include any brackets or pipes (which would break your formatting)

Comment: I've tried using this but I still can't find the way to echo all the possible combinations. Code must work for any sentence entered that has {} and | as separators.